# Dynamic window title in Urxvt with Zsh?

Tags: terminal, x11, zsh

How can I set the window title of Urxvt to the currently running (interactive) command in Zsh shell?

For instance, if I am running `journalctl`, I want `journalctl` to be displayed as the window title. Currently the window title is just showing `urxvt`, which is fine if I am running no commands.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Might be an overkilled solution but installing [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and using its default configuration gives me a dynamic window title. See the following screenshot as an example:

[image]

Comment: Sure is overkill. It, by the way, does exactly what the other answer says; it can be seen in `lib/termsupport.zsh`.

Answer (score 13):

This is possible with the precmd and preexec hooks. I use this for my xterm. It might work unmodified. If not, the place to tweak is the escape sequence to set the terminal title, here ESC, ], 0, ;.

```sh
case $TERM in
  (*xterm* | rxvt)

    # Write some info to terminal title.
    # This is seen when the shell prompts for input.
    function precmd {
      print -Pn "\e]0;zsh%L %(1j,%j job%(2j|s|); ,)%~\a"
    }
    # Write command and args to terminal title.
    # This is seen while the shell waits for a command to complete.
    function preexec {
      printf "\033]0;%s\a" "$1"
    }

  ;;
esac
```